# change src iframe on javascript not working

Tags: javascript, iframe, modal-dialog

i try to chenge the src ifame in js but i cant success.
the i frame always empty and without content of  new window src.
if i put the src inside the iframe its work ( i cant do that becuse i need id to src and i got that on js function)

html:

```
<div class="modal fade" id="myModal" role="dialog">
<div class="modal-dialog modal-lg">
  <div class="modal-content">
    <div class="modal-header">
      <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-body">
  <iframe src=""  id="iframePOP" style="zoom:0.60" width="99.6%" height="250" frameborder="0"></iframe>

    </div>
    <div class="modal-footer">
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-default text-center" data-dismiss="modal">close</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

js:

```
 function ShowPopup(id) {



        $('#myModal').on('show', function () {

                   document.getElementById("iframePOP").src="/Game.aspx?GameId=" + id;


        });
        $('#myModal').modal({ show: true })

    }
```

i tried also this:

```
 function ShowPopup(id) {
        var frameSrc = "/Game.aspx?GameId=" + id;


        $('#myModal').on('show', function () {

            $('iframe').attr("src", frameSrc);


        });
        $('#myModal').modal({ show: true })

    }
```

Comment: where does the `ShowPopup` get called? have you thrown a `debugger` in there to check the value of `id`?

Comment: Show popup called from button with id . The problem  is not a id. I checked the id is fine. I tried with src without id and this stil not work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried assigning your whole domain name into your `var frameSrc`?

EDIT:
Try changing `$('#myModal').on('show', function () { ... } into $('#myModal').is(':visible', function(){ ... });` and make sure the ID of the modal you are referencing is correct. If that didn't work, try this `$('#myModal').on('show.bs.modal', function (e) { ... })`

Comment: Yes i tried the src in js is not work but inside src iframe its work but i need the id so i need use js

Comment: Try changing `$('#myModal').on('show', function () { ... }` into `$('#myModal').is(':visible', function(){ ... });` and make sure the ID of the modal you are referencing is correct. If that didn't work, try this `$('#myModal').on('show.bs.modal', function (e) { ... })`

Comment: $('#myModal').on('show.bs.modal', function (e) { ... })  work! thx very much

Comment: Nice. I've edited my answer so you can mark it as correct. Thanks!